# Golang gin gonic web framework proxy route to another backend

Tags: go, reverse-proxy, go-gin

How to reverse proxy web requests for a few routes to another backend in [Gin Gonic](https://gin-gonic.github.io/gin/) web golang framework

Is there a way to directly forward in the Handle function as shown below?

`router := gin.New()
router.Handle("POST", "/api/v1/endpoint1", ForwardToAnotherBackend)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with the standard library [httputil.ReverseProxy](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httputil/#ReverseProxy).

I haven't found a reason to use gin myself yet, I'm a fan of sticking to stdlib whenever possible.
However I believe you can wrap this ReverseProxy handler in `gin.WrapH()` to be able to use it with your gin router.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Could you give me an example of how to do this?

Comment: @alpha_cod See the link above and then click Example on that page. You simply have to adapt that to the gin framework if you really need to use their router.

Answer (score 13):

This was the solution I used for reverse-proxying a specific subset of endpoints from gin framework to another backend:

```
router.POST("/api/v1/endpoint1", ReverseProxy())
```

and:

```
func ReverseProxy() gin.HandlerFunc {

    target := "localhost:3000"

    return func(c *gin.Context) {
        director := func(req *http.Request) {
            r := c.Request

            req.URL.Scheme = "http"
            req.URL.Host = target
            req.Header["my-header"] = []string{r.Header.Get("my-header")}
            // Golang camelcases headers
            delete(req.Header, "My-Header")
        }
        proxy := &httputil.ReverseProxy{Director: director}
        proxy.ServeHTTP(c.Writer, c.Request)
    }
}
```

Comment: For me it worked only with answer of @kaynAw. https://stackoverflow.com/a/61960275/2908138

Answer (score 1):

when you use director:

```
req.URL.Scheme = "http"
req.Host, req.URL.Host = "google.com", "google.com"
```